# Unable to Send List Of Array via ajax to Controller

Tags: javascript, c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have list of array Generated from dynamically created textbox values .The Issue Is while passing data to controller using ajax ,the count of list is showing in jsonresult but unable to get the list.Its showing Like **[object,Object],[object,Object]** like the image I added.
What I want to retrieve data from list.

**My Data Binding Code**

```
     $('#tbl tbody tr').each(function () {
        var objlist = [];
       
        var count = 0;
        var row = $(this).closest('tr');
        var rowIndex = $(this).closest('tr').index();
        row.find('input[type=text]').each(function () {
           
            count += 1;
                var id    = $(this).attr('id');
                var value = $(this).val();
                var field = $(this).attr('name');
                objlist.push({
                    "Id": id,
                    "field": field,
                    "value": value
                });
                });
       
        tblList.push(objlist);
        });
```

**My Ajax Sending Method**

```
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")',
        data:  {tableData: tblList},
        global: false,
        dataType: "json",
        traditional: true,
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
          ///
            }
        }
    });
```

[image: The List Of arrays]
[image: data After Sending to controller]

[image: Modified Data]

After Modification Its Showing this
Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure you can achieve any reasonable data using `traditional: true,` with that dataset(array of arrays of objects). Maybe you should use JSON.

Comment: I think you may have confused `dataType` (returned type) and `contentType` (what you are sending to the server). Add `contentType="application/json"` and see if things work out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code was tested using Visual Studio and working properly

Ajax should use application/json content type

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")',
        data: JSON.stringify(tblList),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
          ///
            }
        }
    });
```

on server side create a viewmodel

```
public class TableData
{
public int Id {get; set;}
public string Field {get; set;}
public string Value{get; set;}
}
```

and change action header too

```
public JsonResult InsertData([FromBody]List<TableData> tableData)
```

and I think it is a bug in your code you have array inside of another array. You have to fix it before using code

```
      objlist.push({
                    "Id": id,
                    "field": field,
                    "value": value
                });
                });
       
        tblList.push(objlist);
```

if you need 2 arrays try this action

```
public JsonResult InsertData([FromBody] List<List<TableData>> tableData)
```

Comment: Its Not Working Now showing actual count, but values are null. Is this because of i am sending  array list of list ??

Comment: @AsifuzzamanRedoy I am always testing the code, before posting the answer. What shows actual count?

Comment: I have edited the post please see the latest Screen shot @Serge

Comment: @AsifuzzamanRedoy I see 2 arrays of 10 in your picture . How it come?

Comment: Should you have 2 arrays or only one ?

Comment: Well ,The Scenario is I have dynamically generated text boxes from database cell values which will increase/change time to time as my textboxes (array values) will change also. so I  push those values in an arrary list of arrays.   Note: arrary list can be 1-many as its values

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240729/discussion-between-asifuzzaman-redoy-and-serge).